# Trying to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection, code-injection

I have a drop down box set up to allow users to select requirements for economic data. I am trying to prevent sql injection by using mysqli, but I am having no luck. Here is my code:

```
$gYear = $_POST["year"];
$gYear2 = $_POST["year2"];
$gMonth = $_POST["month"];
$gSelect = $_POST["location"];

switch($_POST['location']){
case "loc1":
$column = "Fayette";
break;

case "loc2":
$column = "Henry";
break;

case "loc3":
$column = "Randolph";
break;
case "loc4":
$column = "Rush";
break;

case "loc5":
$column = "Union";
break;

case "loc6":
$column = "Wayne";
break;

case "loc7":
$column = "INCounties";
break;

case "loc8":
$column = "Indiana";
break;

case "loc9":
$column = "Butler";
break;

case "loc10":
$column = "Darke";
break;

case "loc11":
$column = "Mercer";
break;

case "loc12":
$column = "Preble";
break;

case "loc13":
$column = "OHCounties";
break;

case "loc14":
$column = "Ohio";
break;

case "loc15":
$column = "US";
break;
}

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT $column, Year, Month, FROM unemployed WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? and month= ?");

$query->bind_param('s', $gyear, $gYear2, $gMonth);

$query->execute(); 
$result = $query->get_result();

echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Month</th><th>$column</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row->$column;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row->Year;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row->Month;
echo "</td></tr>";

}

$query->close();



echo "</table";

}
```

This isn't working for me. I have been stuck on this for a while. Do you know what parts of my code have issues? I am using PHP 5.3.26. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `bind_param('sss', $gyear, $gYear2, $gMonth);` you missed two `ss`, also you can use `array('loc1' => 'Fayette', ..` and then `if(array_key_exists($_POST['location'], $array)) $column = $array[$_POST['location']]`

Comment: Man, I got tired scrolling this lot even once. You surely have your forefinger aching all the day

Comment: Do I have to create an array? I am not familiar with array_key_exists.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT `".$column."`, `Year`, `Month` FROM `unemployed` WHERE `Year` BETWEEN ? AND ? AND `Month`= ?");
```

Remember to add backquotes before and after column and table names. Besides, remember to match cAsE to how they appear in database. ANd I would also change BETWEEN syntax to more or less option, as I assume you might be missing brackets there.

```
WHERE `YEAR` > ? AND `YEAR` <= ? AND `Month` = ?
```

Comment: For preventing SQL injections you can use old style mysqli_real_escape_string(), although it might break your code in some cases and cause it to stop working, but it still protects well against basic injections.